# Javamail OAuth authentication failed when connecting to Exchange imap using OAuth token

Tags: oauth, outlook, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect to Exchange using Javamail and OAuth. I'm using Javamail 1.5.3 and I referred to [this](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2).

1) The exchange account that I'm trying to connect to is within an org domain. I know that my OAuth token is valid since I'm able to make a Rest api request to https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me to get the user profile using the token. My code looks like this -

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true);
props.put("mail.imap.sasl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable", "true");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect("imap-mail.outlook.com", "xxx@org.com", OAUTH_TOKEN);
```

I get (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException) javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] OAuth authentication failed

2) When I connect to an xxx@outlook.com account, I get 500:Internal Server Error and I'm not able to make the api request above to fetch the user profile using the OAuth token I received.

Comment: Make sure you requested the wl.imap and wl.offline_access scopes.

Comment: @BillShannon, I referred to https://dev.outlook.com/restgettingstarted to register my application. I provided scopes for https://outlook.office.com/mail.read

Comment: Perhaps the scopes need to be capitalized exactly as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/authenticate-Office-365-APIs-using-v2)?  You might also need the offline_access scope, but that's not clear to me.

Comment: @BillShannon , I capitalized it. Still doesn't work. I don't understand the scopes in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243646.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/authenticate-Office-365-APIs-using-v2

Comment: Me neither.  Did you try contacting Microsoft for help?  Did you try requesting wl.imap and wl.offline_access?

Comment: @BillShannon, when I try wl.imap and wl.offline_access, I get invalid scopes in the redirect page.

Comment: Sorry, I think you need help from Microsoft.  I was able to make it work with outlook.com a year and a half ago, but haven't tried recently.